# Why this code generates different numbers?

Tags: hash, cpu, uniqueidentifier, hard-drive

I have this function that creates a unique number for hard-disk and CPU combination.

```
    GetVolumeInformation(drv, szNameBuffer, 256, &dwHddUnique, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL);

    SYSTEM_INFO si;
    GetSystemInfo(&si);

    dwProcessorUnique = si.dwProcessorType + si.wProcessorArchitecture + si.wProcessorRevision;
    dwUniqueKey = dwProcessorUnique + dwHddUnique;
```

It returns different numbers if I format my hard-disk and install a new Windows. Any ideas, why?

Thank you.

### Edit:

OK, Got it (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa364993(VS.85).aspx):

> This function returns the volume
>   serial number that the operating
>   system assigns when a hard disk is
>   formatted. To programmatically obtain
>   the hard disk's serial number that the
>   manufacturer assigns, use the Windows
>   Management Instrumentation (WMI)
>   Win32_PhysicalMedia property
>   SerialNumber.

I should do more research before posting my problems online. Sorry to bother you, let's keep this here in case anybody else can need it.

Comment: Obviously because either `dwProcessorUnique` or `dwHddUnique` changes. Please post no more code than necessary for your question. So, please determine which of the two changes, and then remove the other from the code above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe because when you format  your hard disk it generates a new unique UUID for it? (so `dwHddUnique` would be different)

Comment: Well, It's more or less what I said :)